# Tooltips work in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

In my [web-app](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.html), I implemented some tooltips on buttons with images. In Firefox, they work as expected, that is, they appear right below the button when you hover over that button. However, in Chrome, they appear far left of the button.

CSS:

```css
      .tooltip {
        display: none;
      }
      button:hover .tooltip {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: #ffffaa;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 2px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Times;
      }
```

HTML:

```html
      <div id="simulationButtons">
        <button id="playPauseButton">
          <img
            src="play.svg"
            alt="play"
            id="playImage"
            style="display: inline"
          />
          <img
            src="pause.svg"
            alt="pause"
            id="pauseImage"
            style="display: none"
          />
          <span class="tooltip">Play/Pause</span>
          <!--Didn't know modern browsers don't display alts automatically
              when you hover over an image.-->
        </button>
```

This works as expected in Firefox (this is Firefox for Android, but it looks similar on desktop):
[image: What it looks like in Firefox]

However, for some reason, in Chrome, tooltips are moved to the left of the button (this is Chrome on Android, I haven't managed to install Chrome on my Linux, but I think it will look similar in Chrome on desktop):
[image: What it looks like in Chrome]

So, what is going on in Chrome? How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems to work fine in chrome. The problem is probably somewhere else. Can you post a working code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position:absolute` to position the tooltip so the parent "button" should have `position:relative`

Add this code in your css and it will work fine.

```
#playPauseButton, #fastForwardButton, #singleStepButton, #stopButton {
    position: relative;
}
```

Whenever you make new buttons like these, make sure to add `position:relative` to that button too.

Comment: Your answer is 10 min apart from mine and with the same solution. Why not to vote up instead of duplicating answer?

Comment: your answer was right too but lacking few things so i just mentioned those. I am sorry if you felt bad.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `position:relative` in `<button id="playPauseButton">` or in `<div id="simulationButtons">`

Comment: Well, no, it is not easy to try when I don't have Chrome on this computer.

Comment: why not install chrome?

Comment: How to install Chrome on Oracle Linux? The RPM available on Google is for Fedora and attempt to install it on Oracle Linux gives me a ton of error messages.

Comment: @FlatAssembler [a quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+install+Chrome+on+Oracle+Linux%3F)